# How to have a floating modal controller on top of another controller and have interaction with them at the same time

Tags: swift, modalviewcontroller, floating

I want to know what is best approach for having a floating modal controller on top of another controller like this image:

[image]

As you see, top section of this page is a modal view.

I can implement this top view in the below controller class but I want to have a separate controller for it, but I don't know how to present that class so user have control of the both controllers in same time.

If I create a regular transparent class & present it modally, user will lost interaction contact with the lower controller.

Comment: You can embed a view controller with ***container view***.

Comment: @nayem , how do I handle drag for that container view inside my modal controller class?

Comment: When container view is used, the view controller is no longer a modal view controller, it's embedded view controller. You'll have to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to that container view to control the drag operation.

Comment: Instead of using a view controller you can create a view and in it add pan gesture and fill values in its awakefromnib,also if the view is always visible add it to window that will do:)

Comment: @Shivam Gaur I don't want to do it in my lower controller. I want a separate controller for it.

Comment: you can create your other controller class for view class , just don't make a uiviewcontroller for it , handle actions and gesture in its class that's it, also it depends on your app architecture also, If Im getting somewhere wrong let me know .

Comment: @Shivam Gaur You mean I should create a custom view class for that modal view and handle everything in that class, right?

Comment: @Alfi yes , handle actions in its class.

Comment: @Shivam Gaur, Thanks, I will try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base of @Shivam Gaur suggestion.

I created a custom class & built every thing for handling that top view in there.

[image]

But still I need to handle interactions with subview items in my lower class but its worth the try.

[Here is this GitHub link of this project.](https://github.com/UzumakiAlfredo/DragViewToDismiss/blob/master/README.md)