# Slideable view that can "click" into two places (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to create a slide-up view that will click into one of two places as shown in the below Stock App images. The view slides into the closest spot should it be let go. It also can be tapped on the top to move it automatically. Any ideas on where to get started? I haven't been able to find much help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

[View is down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB2Fb.jpg)

[View is up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdVsC.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a floating modal controller on top of another controller and have interaction with them at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981951/how-to-have-a-floating-modal-controller-on-top-of-another-controller-and-have-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a view with a constant height constraint.
2. Add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to the view.
3. As the user pans you adjust the height constraint by the gesture offset, clamping at the min and max height.
4. When the user lets go you animate the current height to the closest height (min or max).